# Javascript vertical line coming from the bottom of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

My idea is to make almost like a lolipop that has an infinite vertical line coming off of the bottom of a circle (in my case a rectangle). I read that this may be done using css :after but psuedoelements really limit what I want to do. I would prefer to have the line as its own element. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: So put an element inside and position it relatively to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

A `div` with small `width` and a lot more higher `height` would make a perfect "stick".

Example (rectangular lolipop :D):

CSS:

```
#lolipop {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#lolipop .rect {
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#lolipop .stick {
    width: 5px;
    height: 325px;
    background: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="lolipop">
    <div class="rect"></div>
    <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uao97L8q/